# How to set output device properties (e.g. sampling frequency) using AudioGraph

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

I'm writing a simple audio player in UWP that should have the option to set properties of the audio output device, such as bit rate, sampling frequency etc. Is there a way of doing that, preferably using AudioGraph ?

I've tried using EncodingProperties and when checked the PropertyStore, it seemed to work. Unfortunately, I could also set values that were not supported by the device, and the output of that (file), when checked with Audacity, displayed the huge value that I set.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you show some more detailed information, like your test code, your Windows 10 IoT Core device, and your audio output device?